# spamassassin + postfix doesn't work without log files

Tags: postfix, spamassassin

ps aux|grep spamd

```
root     12207  0.0  1.0 159920 83460 ?        Ss   17:38   0:01 /usr/sbin/spamd -d --pidfile=/var/run/spamassassin.pid --create-prefs --max-children 5 --helper-home-dir
root     12208  0.0  0.9 160484 79996 ?        S    17:38   0:00 spamd child
root     12209  0.0  0.9 159920 77788 ?        S    17:38   0:00 spamd child
postfix  16307  0.0  0.1 104608  8816 ?        S    19:18   0:00 smtpd -n smtp -t inet -u -o stress= -o content_filter=spamassassin
```

telnet 127.0.0.1 783

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
SPAMD/1.0
```

cat /etc/postfix/master.conf

```
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
        -o content_filter=spamassassin
#smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       2       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       y       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       y       -       0       tlsproxy
#submission inet n       -       y       -       -       
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
#  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd   -v
        -o content_filter=spamassassin
        -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
        -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
        -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#       -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       y       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache

spamassassin unix - n n - - pipe        user=debian-spamd argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -e /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}
```

from server I send an email test:

```
echo hello|mutt -s test markyoung@gmail.com
```

cat /var/log/mail.log

```
Aug 19 19:23:04 server12 postfix/pickup[16252]: 96BEF281AEC: uid=0 from=<root>
Aug 19 19:23:04 server12 postfix/cleanup[16384]: 96BEF281AEC: info: header Subject: test from local; from=<root@server12> to=<markyoung@gmail.com>
Aug 19 19:23:04 server12 postfix/cleanup[16384]: 96BEF281AEC: message-id=<20170819172304.sxkpxikicu7snioq@server12>
Aug 19 19:23:04 server12 postfix/qmgr[16253]: 96BEF281AEC: from=<root@server12>, size=417, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 19 19:23:04 server12 clamsmtpd: 100057: accepted connection from: 127.0.0.1
Aug 19 19:23:04 server12 postfix/smtpd[16388]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Aug 19 19:23:04 server12 postfix/smtpd[16388]: B2600281780: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Aug 19 19:23:04 server12 postfix/cleanup[16384]: B2600281780: info: header Subject: test from localhost[127.0.0.1]; from=<root@server12> to=<markyoung@gmail.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<server12.org>
Aug 19 19:23:04 server12 postfix/cleanup[16384]: B2600281780: message-id=<20170819172304.sxkpxikicu7snioq@server12>
Aug 19 19:23:04 server12 clamsmtpd: 100057: from=root@server12, to=markyoung@gmail.com, status=CLEAN
Aug 19 19:23:04 server12 postfix/qmgr[16253]: B2600281780: from=<root@server12>, size=633, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug 19 19:23:04 server12 postfix/smtp[16386]: 96BEF281AEC: to=<markyoung@gmail.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10026, delay=0.26, delays=0.1/0.01/0.05/0.11, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as B2600281780)
Aug 19 19:23:04 server12 postfix/smtpd[16388]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1] ehlo=1 xforward=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=6
Aug 19 19:23:04 server12 postfix/qmgr[16253]: 96BEF281AEC: removed
Aug 19 19:23:04 server12 postfix/smtp[16390]: B2600281780: to=<markyoung@gmail.com>, relay=192.168.50.212[192.168.50.212]:25, delay=0.21, delays=0.1/0.01/0.02/0.09, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as D3A0164038F)
Aug 19 19:23:04 server12 postfix/qmgr[16253]: B2600281780: removed
```

No info/error logs but spamassassin doesn't filter any email